# phpMyAdmin errors phpMyAdmin - Error The mysqli extension is missing. IIS Window 7

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have installed PHP by XAMPP and installed mySql on windows 7 and IIS i could see  well. Now when I tried installing phpMyAdmin I am getting following message 
"The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration." 
I have done the INI file setting for

```
 extension=mbstrin
 extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on i
 extension=mysql
```

But still it persist. Any help in this regards will be helpful

Comment: The "mysql" extension is separate from the "mysqli" extension. You'll have to add "extension=mysqli" to the INI file as well.

Comment: Here is the list @Nairou

Comment: Here is the list @Nairou I added . but still it is a issue
;extension=php_mysqli
extension=mysqli
;extension=php_mysql
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
;extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql